# VIM - Stop highlighting extra / trailing white space

Tags: vim, whitespace

[image: vim highlighting extra spaces]

Tried several methods from different websites which didnt stop this highlighting.

Answer (score -1):

After opening a file using vim, type the following command in ESC mode.

`:highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=none guibg=none<CR>`

Alternatively, you can also add a shortcut for this in your ~/.vimrc file as below

`map ss :highlight ExtraWhitespace ctermbg=none guibg=none<CR>`

Comment: Vim doesn't do that if you don't tell it to. Rather than looking for a way to work around a problem you have created, fix the problem itself.